# Opening a ZIP file from variable, not URI in PHP

Tags: php, zip

I try to open a ZIP archive from a variable instead of a file in PHP.

That means there is a file or a MySQL query, I read into a variable $zip_contents or so.
This variable should be passed to a method like ZipArchive::open() instead of the filename.

Is this somehow possible or am I on the wrong track?

Kind regards

zoku

Comment: You could just write it to a temporary file.

Comment: The goal of the whole thing is to keep away from temporary files to avoid slowdowns. It would be nice to do all ZIP actions inside the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you afford little patching of an existing class which unzipps a file? For example, there is a simple solution, involving phpMyAdmin distribution, specifically look into the `libraries` subdirectory. It contains `unzip.lib.php` (GPL). The function `ReadFile` can be easily patched to accept a variable because it reads the file in the first lines and then work with this data. So it only needs to be changed for accepting the data directly.

[Here is](http://www.boonex.com/trac/dolphin/browser/trunk/plugins/myadmin/unzip.lib.php) the direct link to the class.

Comment: This was the thing I was searching for. I used a combination of standard PHP-ZIP-functions (to create archives) and the library you suggested to do the job.